# Infragistics UltraGrid Selected Cell Value

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using UltraGrid from Infragistics and facing a problem when selected a cell value. Whenever I select a cell value it shows as 0.000 as default. I want to show it as 0 or 1. I have already made the changes using the UltraGrid designer but for some reason it always displays 0.0000. The strange thing is that when the collection is bind to the Grid it only contains 0 or 1. Although the datatype for the column is decimal.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to retrieve the current checkbox's value of Infragistics UltraGrid control :

```
private void grid_CellChange(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
        {

// retrieve the current checkbox value

this.grid.Rows[e.Cell.Row.Index].Cells["Selection"].Value = !((bool)this.grid.Rows[e.Cell.Row.Index].Cells["Selection"].Value);

bool selVal = (bool)this.grid.Rows[e.Cell.Row.Index].Cells["Selection"].Value;

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was related to the Decimal type field bound to the column. I changed the field to Double and now it works fine!